# Error while running inspectdb in Django with MySQL Connector and Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm going to post a question and then post the resolution to the problem, I've found the solution after being stuck for some time so I thought it might be valuable for other people using the command inspectdb to generate models in Django from a MySQL database, using MySQL Connector for Python 3.3

command:

```
C:\myproj\myproj> manage.py inspectdb --database=mydb > models.py
```

Resulting Error (Traceback omitted for brevity):

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''decimal' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is very quick, please note that the credits go to Marcin Miklaszewski who posted the bug and the related solution here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72478
However I thought that it would have been easier to find here on StackOverflow.

There is an error in line 65 of the file (Assuming you have python installed in C:\Python33):

```
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\introspection.py
```

replace the line 65:

```
"table_schema = DATABASE() AND data_type='decimal", [table_name])"
```

with:

```
"table_schema = DATABASE() AND data_type='decimal'", [table_name])"
```

(note the missing apostrophe after the word `decimal` in the first version).

Now your inspectdb command will run correctly.